# Grep search for redirects in .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess, grep, putty

I have here code for search all .htaccess files in all folders and subfolders

`\find ./ \( -name ".htaccess" \) -type f -exec grep -il '' {} \;`

How should it looks to find all .htaccess and in those files find all redirects?
To make list of .htaccess files and all redirects in each file?

Comment: Can you provide a sample `.htaccess` file and the sample output you expect the commands to produce?

Comment: all htaccess contain something like this:

 `RedirectMatch 301 ^/path/index.html http://www.target.page`
And I need to have output like:
`path/to/.htaccess originalPage redirectedPage` its like table with Column1 for path to redirect Column2 is original page and Column3 is redirected page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use find in combination with xargs:

`find . -name .htaccess | xargs grep ^RedirectMatch`

Oh i have missed a part of your task. To get a formatted list you could pipe this output through sed to get rid of the `:RedirectMatch` part and finally delegate your output through another pipe into awk:

`find . -name .htaccess | xargs grep ^RedirectMatch | sed 's/:RedirectMatch//' | awk '{printf "%s %s %s\n", $1, $3, $4}'`

Comment: I'm sorry, since i do not use putty i can not help you out with this. The command works when im using it in a normal shell (tested with bash and busybox sh). Your initial post looks like you have to escape some characters for input into putty...

Comment: and is it possible to add there also path to .htaccess file? Now it returns just redirects without .htaccess

Comment: If the path to .htaccess appears at first position in the matched string, $1 will display it. Just play around with awk a little bit and i'm sure you find a satisfying solution. My output looks like: `/home/user/src/htaccess/sub/.htaccess:RedirectMatch ^/path/index.html http://www.target.page
/home/user/src/htaccess/.htaccess:RedirectMatch ^/path/index.html http://www.target.page`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive `grep` command as shown below:

```
grep -r --include=.htaccess RedirectMatch .
```

This will print out the file name and the redirect within the file.

Comment: After using this command in putty it wrote: `grep: illegal option -- -
grep: illegal option -- d
usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...`

Comment: Looks like your version of `grep` doesn't support the `--include` option. Check your `man` page to confirm.